# Visual Studio 2019 Project creation Issue

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019

Every time I try to install Visual Studio 2019, installation is successful but when i create new project  I get the error

[image: Every time I try to install Visual Studio 2019, I get the error]

Any help or suggestion would be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the related component nuget packages are not stored under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Packages`. They should be stored when you executing Installation process. Not sure why this happens.

Try this:

1. make sure that your os account has the authority to modify and control C disk.
2. run `vs_installer` as **Administrator** and then click [Repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).